# Write some content on next page using javascript function window.print()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing

In my ASP.NET MVC View I wrote the following code to print the content of my web page.

```
        var newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.document.write()

        newWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("sbmtform").innerHTML);
        newWindow.print();
```

I have another div that i want to be printed on next page in the same document. Please guide how to add pages or how can i go the the next page and write my content.

Comment: Can't you just do another `newWindow.document.write` again? It's not clear what the issue is. What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: `window.print()` does not write content to anything ... except a printer maybe

Comment: @ADyson I want to print a table on the next page in the same document. Like we use <br> to skip to the next line, is there a way to skip to the next page in javascript?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it opens the printing panel. Actually i have written content in newWindow. And then called window.print() to print that content.

Comment: So what is the issue

Comment: Ah so you want it to create a new page on paper. Sorry "page" in web programming means a web page normally, not a printed page. You'd just have to add enough line breaks until it went to the next page. But of course you cannot control what size paper the user decides to print onto, or whether they use portrait or landscape, so you can't assume anything about the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a CSS directive:

```
@media print {
    .mynewpage {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

and in HTML

```
<br class="mynewpage">
```

See also https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp

If you don't have CSS, you can also do:

```
<br style="page-break-after: always;">
```

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wish your end-users to print the entire web page with all UI controls. Consider using a specific [reporting tool](https://demos.devexpress.com/XtraReportsDemos/ReportTypes/Subreports.aspx) to generate and print data-based documents.